# Xcode's colored console output

Tags: xcode, debugging

Is possible to format/color the output in the Xcode console? I know that you can do that while debugging CoreData on Mac by setting:
`com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` and
`com.apple.CoreData.SyntaxColoredLogging YES`

What with our own logs, can we color/format them too somehow?

Answer (score 21):

I found a plug-in that supports console logging in ANSI color-codes here: http://deepitpro.com/en/articles/XcodeColors/info/

There's also a fork of this same code that works well and uses a custom syntax to color the text: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors

Comment: And if you use Cocoa Lumberjack, the code colouring is done automatically for you...