# About xcode console text color and background

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Cannot change text color of xcode color output despite trying to use the "xcode preference" dialogue box.  Please help ...

[image]

The above is a screen shot of the preference dialogue window.  Somehow, the option for changing the console output does not seem to be showing up.

Comment: It's in Preferences >> Debugging. Also this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749955/xcodes-colored-console-output

Comment: crunchyt, thanks for the comment.  But after trying the Preferences >> Debugging screen, the console output font and background color still cannot be changed ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under **Debugging >> Fonts & Colors** you can set fonts the following way;:

**1. Debugger Console Prompt** = the color text prompt when breakpointing

**2. Debugger Console Input** = the color of typed text when breakpointing

**3. Executable Standard Output** = most of the debug text, you can change the foreground color. This accounts for most of the debugger output text.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the background color, but you may have more luck with Xcode 4 themes instead of 3.2.x

**Here's the working output (minus some redacted info):**
[image: Colorful Xcode Debugger Output PLUS any BG color you want as long as it's white!]

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.  Have been wondering about the meaning of the Console Prompt, Input, Output etc every time I come across them.  Great that you provide the info to me.  But I really wish to have a black background.  So Xcode 4 might be the only solution to this as you have suggested ...