# C++ Xcode- How to output color

Tags: c++

I have a question is how do I output colors in Xcode? I'm using the latest version of it, I have my application output in the console. How would I output something like `Hello World` when Hello is `green`, and World is `blue`?

How would I output colors in the terminal / Command Prompt, is it possible to do it for both? For something like having different colors like Hello be green and World be Blue, so I can change the color anytime so it isn't just the same colors the entire time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode's colored console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749955/xcodes-colored-console-output)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260226/about-xcode-console-text-color-and-background?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It all depends on the terminal in which you run your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xcode->preference->console-Basic->fonts and color ->Console->Executable Console output (then select color)**
**Xcode Console**
[image: Setting color preference]

**For Terminal**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#define RESET   "\033[0m"
#define BLACK   "\033[30m"      /* Black */
#define RED     "\033[31m"      /* Red */
#define GREEN   "\033[32m"      /* Green */
#define YELLOW  "\033[33m"      /* Yellow */
#define BLUE    "\033[34m"      /* Blue */
#define MAGENTA "\033[35m"      /* Magenta */
#define CYAN    "\033[36m"      /* Cyan */
#define WHITE   "\033[37m"      /* White */
#define BOLDBLACK   "\033[1m\033[30m"      /* Bold Black */
#define BOLDRED     "\033[1m\033[31m"      /* Bold Red */
#define BOLDGREEN   "\033[1m\033[32m"      /* Bold Green */
#define BOLDYELLOW  "\033[1m\033[33m"      /* Bold Yellow */
#define BOLDBLUE    "\033[1m\033[34m"      /* Bold Blue */
#define BOLDMAGENTA "\033[1m\033[35m"      /* Bold Magenta */
#define BOLDCYAN    "\033[1m\033[36m"      /* Bold Cyan */
#define BOLDWHITE   "\033[1m\033[37m"      /* Bold White */

int main() {

std::cout << GREEN << "hello"
      <<BLUE<<"world" << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: I'm asking how would you have something like Hello be green, and World be blue

Comment: Then why did you choose this answer to be helpful.

Comment: You can shorten the bold colors using semicolons to `BOLDBLACK   "\033[1;30m"` if you want.