# I want to make my console more colorful. How can I make the user input (obtained through getline) colorful while they type?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering if it is possible to color text while the user is typing it into the console.

I am using a color library for `cout`'ed text, but I wanted to know if it's possible to color the text while the user is inputting his/her string?

Comment: yes its possible but depends on IDE you are using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526532/c-xcode-how-to-output-color/45526627#45526627

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @HariomSingh I don't need to output the color, I need to change the color of the user input while they are typing it (using getline)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows console APIs to do so:

```
HANDLE console_output = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
::SetConsoleTextAttribute(console_output, FOREGROUND_GREEN);

std::string buffer;
std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

::CloseHandle(console_output);
```

Input text will be green in color. Also, don't forget to include windows.h

Answer (score 1):

On linux/macOS just do as following :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string foo;
  std::cout << "Type your text here : \x1B[31m";
  std::cin >> foo;
  std::cout << "\x1B[0m" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Your input : " << foo << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

A litte explanation :

when you type one of the followings specific strings :

```
"\x1B[31m" (red)
"\x1B[32m" (green)
"\x1B[33m" (yellow)
"\x1B[34m" (blue)
"\x1B[35m" (magenta)
"\x1B[36m" (cyan)
"\x1B[0m" (reset)
```

it will use termcap (stand for terminal capabilities) and change the color of all the output written after.
Don't forget to reset after using these termcap otherwise your terminal will stuck to the chosen color until you reset it.

PS : Don't know if it works for windows.